# Waiting forever for Android boot animation to finish

Tags: android, beagleboard, android-launcher

I'm currently programming an android launcher for rowboat android (2.3.3) on the Beagleboard xM. Booting android normally works perfectly, but for some reason when I set my app as the default launcher and restart the device, android gets stuck in the boot animation.

I have read from the logs that my app is booting and starting the required services. To get the boot animation to finish, using code like this causes the screen to finally be drawn:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        switch(view.getId()){
            ...
            case R.id.mainmenu_history:
                ft.replace(R.id.detailContainer, new FragmentHistoryMain());
                break;
            ...
            default:
                break;
        }
        ft.commit();
```

Once the code completes, there is an entry in logcat:

```
    SurfaceFlinger: Boot Completed (24231 ms)
```

And then everything runs perfectly. Do launchers need to send some kind of broadcast intent to finish the boot animation?

I have also disabled the keyguard using `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);` as this launcher is for a specific project.

I'm completely stuck and apart from putting in a Thread.sleep() followed by a fragment transaction, out of ideas. Can anyone help?